# Any extreme circumstance when a substantially probably prevailing party can ask for some immediate injunction that they be provided attorney's fees?

Tags: california, civil-law, us-constitution, attorney-fees, fourteenth-amendment

Let's say, in California, a Forbes 500 multi-billionaire wrongdoer has engaged and continues to engage in such fraudulent and/or malicious **and** oppressive conduct that has made plaintiff and continues to make plaintiff entirely disabled from, impossible or extremely difficult to (i) earn as it is sufficient for the basic necessaries of life and (ii) to afford even housing let alone an attorney, if for the purposes of pre-trial discovery or otherwise, the plaintiff shows that it is substantially probable that they will prevail in a certain cause of action, can that be used enjoined with a Four-Teenth Amendment argument to request reasonable attorney's fees to be provided for such cause of action to be brought before the court or be amended properly as otherwise it is impossible for plaintiff and plaintiff is disable to present his case in equity under Amendment Four-Teen?

If so, is there any close or remotely close authority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent a divorce or termination of parental rights case (and certain cases of a probate/trust character), this would almost never happen.

In divorce, probate and trust cases, the party may have an equitable interest in property controlled by another which justifies a pre-merits determination award out of property that is really their's not due to the merits outcome.

In termination of parents rights cases, the right to fees in this litigation with the state is by analogy to the right to a state paid attorney in criminal matters established in the *Gideon* case.

Comment: Could 28 U.S. Code § 1915 be pioneered maybe on the analogy of the _Gideon_ case or by compelling a judge to ask action from the Legislation? (Your comments already made me love this forum, and be completely obsessed with it! )

Comment: yes, _in forma pauperis_, under Government Code §§ 68630-68641, and yes, those do not provide for representation or even assistance. bdb484's comment though claims representative may also be appointed in federal court though I'm not* versed in the statute myself.

Comment: Sometimes a court can appoint counsel to a case when no party supports a position that needs to be defended, see, e.g., the Amistad case and some cases challenging the constitutionality of legislation that no party in the trial court defends. But, AFAIK, this isn't under 28 USC § 1915.

Comment: I missed 28 USC § 1915(e)(1) at first glance. I suspect that this may be pro bono service until there is a post-trial award of fees. Not very familiar with it. Some related case law discussed at https://www.scotusblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/16-287-BIO.pdf

Comment: On point: "28 USC 1915(e)(1) states that a federal court "may request an attorney to represent any person unable to afford counsel." The Supreme Court has said that this provision does not give a court the authority to "appoint" counsel, but rather can only ask an attorney to serve willingly.  *Mallard v. United States District Court*, 490 U.S. 296 (1989).  The statute also does not provide for compensation for appointed counsel."

Comment: That's great! I think the rationale to allow for justice to be achieved equally and without regard to socioeconomic status is clear, but of course, that is not a matter of a defendant until they are prevailed against.

Comment: _Mallard v. United States District Court_, 490 U.S. 296 (1989) wouldn't this be the same in the case of criminal defendants, too under Amendment VI?

Comment: @AlmasySephirot No. Indigent defendants in criminal cases have a constitutional and statutory right under other statutes to government paid defense counsel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124638/discussion-between-almasy-sephirot-and-ohwilleke).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a thing that can happen.

If the case is in federal court, [28 U.S. Code § 1915](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1915) permits the court to appoint counsel to represent an indigent plaintiff. In state courts, my understanding is that California law only permits the court to appoint plaintiff's counsel in certain family-law matters.

If the defendant's case to avoid liability is frivolous, you can seek sanctions at basically any stage in the litigation, but you would be limited to collecting your legal fees up to that point; you would not be permitted to force the opposing party to fund your case in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would 28 U.S. Code § 1915 allow for such appointment _before_ the filing of the complaint, filed confidentially, without the other party to look for information that would prejudice the causes or in any other ways without prejudice and  case since filing would lead to an issue around _Twombly_ and _Iqbal_ which wouldn't apply in California Superior Courts?

Comment: An interesting question! Feel free to post it as a new question and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, I'll go right ahead!